# How to pass a list to view and filter them based on Overtime. fx show all employees then filtered ones in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i am still learning asp.net core.
i have to show a list of all employees then i could filter them based on over time.

i am consuming web api which has two urls

**employees with overtime**

api/employee?hasOverTime=true

**all employees**

/api/employee

Controller

```
           public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool hasOverTime = false)
    {
       

       
        var employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44308/api/employee"))
            {
                string apiResponce = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                employeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(apiResponce);
            }
        }



        if (hasOverTime == true)
        {

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44308/api/employee?hasOvertime=true"))
                {
                    string apiResponce = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    employeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(apiResponce);
                }


            }


        }

        

        return View(employeeList);
    }
```

There must be a way to filter whether you want to see
All Employees
Overtime Employees
Regular Employees

and another problem i can not figure out is how to return the sum of all monthly payments. Similar to the other GET method, I should be able to filter by overtime, given a boolean parameter.

```
            public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public double HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public double HoursPerMonth { get; set; }
    public decimal GetMonthlyPay()
    {

        double overTimeHours = HoursPerMonth - 150;
        double pay;

        if (overTimeHours <= 0)
        {
            pay = HourlyWage * HoursPerMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (150 * HourlyWage) + (overTimeHours * HourlyWage * 1.5);
        }
        return (decimal)pay;
    }
}
```

Service

```
         public decimal GetTotalMonthlyExpense(List<Employee> employee)
    {

        return employee.Sum(e => e.GetMonthlyPay());
         
        

        //decimal sum = _employeeContext.employees.Sum(e => e.GetMonthlyPay());
        
    }
```

Web Api Controller

```
             [HttpGet("payments")]
    public decimal Payments(List<Employee> sum)
    {
        List<Employee> sumpayment = new();

        return _employeeservice.GetTotalMonthlyExpense(sumpayment);

    
    }
```

it does not work

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pass true or false to filter the overtime employees?

You can check my demo, for example, to filter overtime worker and get the total salary, use linq

'where' to **filter the overtime first** to a list, and create a new list selected
from the **filtered list** to

**put their own salary** , then you just need to **Sum each employee's salary** to get the total salary.

The procedures are all in this action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getemp(bool hasOverTime)
    {
        if (hasOverTime == false)
        {
            var employeeList = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.HoursPerMonth <= 150).ToList(); 
            var payList = (from u in employeeList
                               select new
                               {
                                   Salary = u.HourlyWage*u.HoursPerMonth
                               })
                       .ToList();  
            ViewData["totalneedtopay"] = payList.Sum(x => x.Salary); 
            return View(employeeList);
        }
        else  //overtime
        {
            var employeeList = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.HoursPerMonth > 150).ToList(); //all the employees who work overtime
            var payList = (from u in employeeList
                           select new
                           {
                               Salary = u.HourlyWage * 150+1.5*(u.HourlyWage*(u.HoursPerMonth-150))
                           })
                       .ToList();//each employee's salary
            ViewData["totalneedtopay"] = payList.Sum(x => x.Salary); //total salary
            return View(employeeList);
        }                       
    }
```

To get the total, you can use a viewdata to pass the value:

**Set the viewdata:**

```
ViewData["totalneedtopay"] = payList.Sum(x => x.Salary);
```

**to use in View:**

```
Total:@ViewData["totalneedtopay"]
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tisa. it really helped me with your help and adding this it solved the problem.


<a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index" asp-route-hasOverTime="false">employee - overtime</a>


<a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index" asp-route-hasOverTime="true">employee + overtime</a>


<a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">All Employees</a>


I have one problem can you show me how to show sum of all salaries in the view? 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
         <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index" asp-route-hasOverTime="false">employee - overtime</a>
          <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index" asp-route-hasOverTime="true">employee + overtime</a>
          <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">All Employees</a> 








         public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? hasOverTime, decimal sum)
    {



        
        var employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        employeeList = await HttpRestApi(employeeList);



        if (hasOverTime == true)
        {
            employeeList = employeeList.Where(e => e.HoursPerMonth > 150).ToList();

            sum = employeeList.Sum(s => s.GetMonthlyPay());
            ViewBag.Totalpay = sum;
            return View(employeeList);
        }
        else if (hasOverTime == false)
        {
            employeeList = employeeList.Where(e => e.HoursPerMonth <= 150).ToList();
            sum = employeeList.Sum(s => s.GetMonthlyPay());
            ViewBag.Totalpay = sum;

            return View(employeeList);

        }



        else {

            var employee = employeeList.ToList();
            
            sum = employeeList.Sum(s => s.GetMonthlyPay());
            ViewBag.Totalpay = sum;


            return View(employee);

        }



    }
```